# PHP open new page after query execution

Tags: php, html, form-submit

I have a form in my webpage in which 'action' specifies a php file to execute a query. I want to execute that query on button press and open a new web page named details.php. How can I do that? the query works fine..after executing the query it should open the details.php page.My code for output printing is given below..thanks in advance

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{
echo "The image has been uploaded, and your information has been added";  
}
else {
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
```

I need this result to be printed in a webpage(page dimensions same as that of previous data entering page) with a home button

It is ok even if the same page displays the result, but then the data in form should be cleared, so that user can enter new data

Comment: Simply you can use `header('location:your_file.php');`

Comment: @LearneR can you show where header is to be inserted in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In it's simplest form,

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{
   $msg = "The image has been uploaded, and your information has been added";
   $size = <place the value here>
   $filename = <place file name here>
   header("Location: details.php?msg={$msg}&size={$size}&fn={$filename}&target={$target}");
   exit();
}
else {
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
```

Then in `details.php`

```
$msg = $_GET['msg'];
$size = $_GET['size'];
$fn = $_GET['fn'];
$destination = $_GET['target'];

echo "<p>".$msg."</p>";
echo "<p>File size is: ".$size."</p>";
echo "<p>File name is: ".$fn."</p>";
echo "<p>File uploaded at :".$destination."</p>";
echo "<input type='button' value='Home' onclick='window.location.href=\"home.php\"' />";
```

PS : Don't forget to sanitize all data

Answer (score 0):

using `header()` will only navigate the page the user is currently on to your desired page. In order to create a new popup window with desired dimensions, you have to use JavaScript.

You can use AJAX to process a request and have PHP return a message to the client side JS to trigger the new popup page to open.

Comment: Not entirely true. He could pass the data through query strings too using `header()` and then grab them on the page that it is being redirected to

Comment: asprin, can  you be more specific and show how it can be done? thanks

Comment: He specifically wanted a new popup page with a desired dimension and buttons when displaying the new page. In order to do that, he needs JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, I don't see a request for popup anywhere in his question.